# Different behaviour for MFMessageComposeViewController in IOS 5.0 & 6.0

Tags: ios, ipad, imessage

I am facing 2 issues with `MFMessageComposeViewController` in `iOS 6.0`

- In `iOS 6.0` when we are dismissing the keyboard with `cursor in the message body text view`, the message body text-view disappears. But when we do the same operation with `To text field`, its working fine. Its working fine in iOS 5.0. The issue seems to be only in `iOS 6.0`.
- When dismissing the keyboard, a transparent gap appears at the top of `message body text view` (see the attached images below).

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you post the code you are using?

Comment: if ([messageClass canSendText]) {
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageComposer = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
            if(![[notification.object valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"] isEqualToString:@""])
{
NSArray *recepient = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[notification.object valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"], nil];
                messageComposer.recipients = recepient;
            }
messageComposer.body = @"Greetings frm Ram, happy Bday";
messageComposer.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:messageComposer animated:YES];
[messageComposer release];
  }

Comment: Did you faced this issue?

Comment: Please add this and check..messageComposer.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES;

Comment: Tried. But No change.. Still same problem.